# 3D point cloud to 2.5D graycale image (metric) [Halcon?]

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d, point-cloud, geometry

I have a problem ragarding transferring a point cloud to a 2.5D metric grayscale image (gray value gives depth information). I start with a three channel image of 32bit floats with each pixel representing the three coordinates in mm (metric).

Halcon is the preferred library, but not necessary.

I hope that someone can help me.

Greetings from Stuttgart, Germany

Max

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I do not know how to transfer a point cloud to 2.5D metric grayscale image. (operators??)

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: If I misunderstood the question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your 3 channels already give you the 3D coordinates, and from that 3 images, you already know which pixels locations the 3D data are projected. So you don't need to do anything. If you like to get a depth image, just set:
$$
depth(i,j) = z(i,j)
$$
In Halcon, you just select the Z-channel using `access_channel`.
If you desire a distance image, then:
$$
distance(i,j) = \lVert (x,y,z)^T \rVert
$$
The norm defines the distance metric you would like to use. Traditionally, I would say Euclidean $\|\cdot\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. You could do this in any language by using operations like addition, multiplication and square roots.